# Appending data with additional information to text in a file

Tags: python

I have a text file containing thousands of lines of code and I would like to replace certain elements as follows:

Text from file1:

```
serverfarm host foobar2:443
  failaction reassign
  probe tcp111-probe
  rserver foobar1 443
  rserver foobar2 443
```

Text with additional information that I would like to append to original file text (file2):

```
rserver host foobar1
  ip address 1.1.1.1
  inservice
rserver host foobar2
  ip address 1.1.1.2
  inservice
```

So we can see that in the original file the `rserver` line does not capture the IP address but I have this information in the other file.

Before:

```
rserver foobar1 443
```

After (desired output)

`rserver foobar1 443` <--- Keep original text

`rserver host foobar1`  <--- This and following two lines should be added below original text

```
ip address 1.1.1.1

inservice
```

There is a direct mapping between the original text string `"rserver foobar1 443"` (remove 3rd text block) and the first line of the replacement text `"rserver host foobar1"` (remove 2nd text block = host).

Is it possible to do this with a python dictionary or similar approach?  I would appreciate it if someone could show me how to do this in Python and I will then use this approach when doing similar tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a dictionary or [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to map server names from the second file and their list of details (ip and service status) and insert these details while writing into a new file:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

d = defaultdict(list)
with open('file1.txt') as f1, open('file2.txt') as f2, open('output.txt', 'w') as f3:
    for line in f2:
        if 'host' in line:
            key = line.strip().replace('host ', '')
        d[key].append('  ' + line) # match indentation in file1 with leading spaces

    for line in f1:
        f3.write(line if '\n' in line else line+'\n')
        if 'rserver' in line:
            f3.writelines(d[re.sub(r'\s\d+', '', line.strip())])
```

---

*output.txt*:

```
serverfarm host foobar2:443
  failaction reassign
  probe tcp111-probe
  rserver foobar1 443
  rserver host foobar1
    ip address 1.1.1.1
    inservice
  rserver foobar2 443
  rserver host foobar2
    ip address 1.1.1.2
    inservice
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to write a custom parser/translator like the following:

```
replacements = {}
with open('file2.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        l = l.strip()
        if l.startswith('rserver'):
            server_header = l
            server = l.split()
            server_name = server[2]
        elif 'ip address' in l:
            ip_address = l
        elif 'service' in l:
            service = l
            replacements[server_name] = (server_header, ip_address, service)

with open('file1.txt') as f, open('out.txt', 'w') as out:
    for l in f:
        l = l.rstrip()
        if 'rserver' in l:
            server = l.split()
            server_name = server[1]
            out.write(l + '\n')
            out.write('  ' + replacements[server_name][0] + '\n')
            out.write('    ' + replacements[server_name][1] + '\n')
            out.write('    ' + replacements[server_name][2] + '\n')                
        else:
            out.write(l + '\n')
```

**Output** *(out.txt)*

```
serverfarm host foobar2:443
  failaction reassign
  probe tcp111-probe
  rserver foobar1 443
  rserver host foobar1
    ip address 1.1.1.1
    inservice
  rserver foobar2 443
  rserver host foobar2
    ip address 1.1.1.2
    inservice
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a Linux distro, then you can use awk command and pipe it with grep.

If you want a solution with python, then the complexity is going to be O(n.m), where n is the number of lines in first file and m is the number of lines in second file.

Algorithm in python:

```
open a new file, file3
file1 = f.open(path to file 1)
n = number of lines in file1
file2 = f.open(path to file 2)
m = number of lines in file 2
for i in range(n):
   r = readline(file1)
   copy line into file3
   convert r to array and check to see if r[0] is "rserver"
   if r[0]=="rserver" then:
      for j in range(m):
         k = readline(file2)
         convert k to array and check to see if k[0] is "rserver"
         if k[0]=="rserver" then:
            merge required number of lines from file2 into file3
            increment j by x
close all files
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Disagree with your complexity assessment, the complexity of my approach is O(n)